# table X has no column named Y - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy library in python for mapping my database. I have created a file contains my database and it runs without problems. But when I create a new row specifying my values, I get an error says

> table menu_item has no column named description

```
 class MenuItem(Base):

        __tablename__ = 'menu_item'

        name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        course = Column(String(80))
        description = Column(String(250))
        price = Column(String(8))
        restaurant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('restaurant.id'))
        restaurant = relationship(Restaurant)
```

This is my class MenuItem 
And here is my row value.

```
Cheesepizza = MenuItem(
    name="Chesse Pizza",
    description="Made with all natural ingredients and hot mozzarilla",
    course='Entree', price='$8.99', restaurant=myFirstRestaurant)
```

I expect that I should assign 5 values to each row. Do I miss something?

Comment: Have you perhaps modified your models after creating the tables, adding said column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out, I created a database firstly without the description column but when I added it and ran the python file again, it did not update the file to add the column (Which I don't know why) so, I had to remove the .db file and run the python file to recreate the database and it worked out.

Comment: You probably figured it out since then, but you need to know that SQLAlchemy on its own will not migrate your database schemas. It will only produce DDL (CREATE TABLE statements and similar) to create a brand new database. The SQLAlchemy team has a separate project called Alembic to handle database schema migrations. In the meantime, some hand-written SQL will do the job: `ALTER TABLE menu_item ADD COLUMN description varying char(250);` (adjust accordingly)

Comment: Note that SQLite will not let you drop or change columns from a schema, so if you need to do so, you can use a migration tool (e.g. Alembic) or [you can do it manually through a process that basically involves creating a new table with your desired columns, transferring the values to that table, dropping the old table, renaming the new table back to the old table's name, recreating all the relevant triggers and views associated to the old table, updating the relevant views and hoping that you have not goofed up](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also just drop all the tables and recreate them, rather than recreating the entire db itself. Something like the following (not full code context, but just some key snippets)

```
import connexion
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = connex_app.app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
```

Alternatively, you could try dropping the table itself, but I've had mixed results with this.

```
MenuItems.__table__.drop(db.engine)
```